# Could not find artifact org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:jar: in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to add cxf-codegen-plugin, but getting below error :-

> Could not find artifact org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:pom: in
> central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) Could not find artifact
> org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:jar: in central
> (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Snipped from my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                <target>${java.version}</target> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>locate-wsdl</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/name.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <wsdlLocation>name.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Did you have special repo settings? The plugin can be found at the  regular maven repo: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-codegen-plugin

Comment: try adding version to the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Your setting.xml file can be wrong.
Settings.xml file can be found in .m2 folder.
Try using this one:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>adobe-public</id>
            <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>adobe-public-releases</id>
                <name>Adobe Public Repository</name>
                <url>https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

This library is public availible so the only reason why you can not download it, is connection with maven repository.